# How to split result of coalesce function in two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We have three tables

- Person_Table
- Phone_Table
- Primary_Phone_Table

All the phone number(primary and non-primary Table) is in format "areacode-Phonenumber" (123-5434) or Null. I want to extract area code from Phone_Number column and show it as a separate column of area code in my select query.

The query used is like this.

```
SELECT person_number,
       COALESCE ((SELECT phone_number
                    FROM Primary_phone_table PPHT
                   WHERE PPHT.person_id = PT.person_id),
                 (SELECT phone_number
                    FROM phone_table PHT
                   WHERE PHT.person_id = PT.person_id)) Phone_Number
  FROM Person_Table PT
```

Desired O/P:

| Person_Number | Phone_Number | Area_Code |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: You can `select phone_number from ( your query here )` for a convenient way to use the phone_number multiple times in your query (at least once to extract the area code, once to extract the local number). You can use a combination of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to extract the parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doing it in a more complex way than it should be? Why those subqueries instead of joins? Couldn't query (you posted) be rewritten to

```
SELECT pt.person_number,
       coalesce(ppht.phone_number, pht.phone_number) phone_number
  FROM person_table pt
  LEFT JOIN primary_phone_table ppht ON ppht.person_id = pt.person_id
  LEFT JOIN phone_table pht ON pht.person_id = pt.person_id;
```

I think it could, and it should. Code you wrote might raise `TOO_MANY_ROWS` if someone has more than a single phone number.

---

In order to extract area code and phone number (separated by a "minus" sign), a simple option is to use `substr` + `instr` functions combination. Current query can be used as a "source" (either as a subquery or a CTE (the `WITH` factoring clause)). For example:

```
WITH
   current_query
   AS
      (SELECT pt.person_number,
              COALESCE (ppht.phone_number, pht.phone_number) phone_number
         FROM person_table pt
         LEFT JOIN primary_phone_table ppht ON ppht.person_id = pt.person_id
         LEFT JOIN phone_table pht ON pht.person_id = pt.person_id)
SELECT c.person_number,
       SUBSTR (c.phone_number, 1, INSTR (c.phone_number, '-') - 1) area_code,
       SUBSTR (c.phone_number, INSTR (c.phone_number, '-') + 1) phone_number
  FROM current_query c;
```

---

With some sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     current_query (person_number, phone_number)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, '123-5454' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT c.person_number,
  8         SUBSTR (c.phone_number, 1, INSTR (c.phone_number, '-') - 1) area_code,
  9         SUBSTR (c.phone_number, INSTR (c.phone_number, '-') + 1) phone_number
 10    FROM current_query c;

PERSON_NUMBER AREA_CODE  PHONE_NUMBER
------------- ---------- ------------
            1 123        5454
            2

SQL>
```

Comment: At least the Primary_phone_table shoud be outer joined (which is why they use COALESCE at all, I think - there can be persons without a primary phone number). In order to get also persons without any phone, you'd have to outer join Phone_table, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query .

```
SELECT pt.person_number,
       coalesce(ppht.phone_number, pht.phone_number) phone_number,
       SUBSTR(coalesce(ppt.phone_number, pht.phone_number),1,regexp_instr(ppt.phone_number,'[-].*') - 1) area_code
FROM person_table pt
LEFT JOIN primary_phone_table ppt ON ppt.person_id = pt.person_id
LEFT JOIN phone_table pht ON pht.person_id = pt.person_id;
```